# Doctrine 2 update from entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to update an entity in a similar way as below:

```
$data       = new ATest();  // my entity
$data->id   = 1;            // id 1 already exists, I just want to update this row
$data->name = "ORM Tested"; // changed the name

$entityManager->persist($data);
$entityManager->flush();
```

This will insert and change the id of the object instead of updating the existing row in the database.

Comment: how come you can set the id manually? Isn't ID a protected property?

Comment: no it's not if you don't make it

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had to use

```
$entityManager->merge($data)
```

Comment: Take a note that you should copy it back into $data. ie: `$data = $entityManager->merge($data)`

Comment: How do you figure that? I'm not seeing it in the current docs. Perhaps it changed since 2013. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw In the link you referenced `// $entity now refers to the fully managed copy returned by the merge operation.` otherwise $data would reference the instantiated, detached or unmanaged object. The process can be validated in 2.5 at `\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::doMerge` where it creates a new instance of the class otherwise returns the retrieved entity from the database.

Comment: This `merge` doesn't work if it the children with `@OneToMany`

Comment: merge function is deprecated now (doctrine 2.7)

Answer (score 93):

You should call merge instead of persist:

```
$data = new MyEntity();
$data->setId(123);
$data->setName('test');

$entityManager->merge($data);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: I think someone changed his answer here so mine doesn't look very useful anymore...

Comment: Merge is required for unmanaged entities e.g (in my case) the entity was instantiated through deserialization

Comment: Thanks @francesco, how to give a where condition like **id='1'**

Comment: @rubin if you look at my example, that would be as doing `UPDATE my_entity_table SET name = 'test' WHERE id = 123;` (unless you change the ID as well like I did but it's not usually possible since Doctrine doesn't automatically generate setters on primary keys).

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `getReference` to update an entity property by identifier without retrieving the database state.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies

This will establish a simple Proxy to work with the Entity by ID instead of instantiating a `new Entity` or explicitly getting the Entity from the database using `find()`, which can then be updated by flush.

```
$data = $entityManager->getReference('ATest', $id);
$data->setName('ORM Tested');
$entityManager->flush();
```

This is especially useful for updating the `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` associations of an entity.
EG: `$case->addTest($data);`

It is generally bad practice to manually set the identifier of a new Entity, even if the intent is to update the entity. Instead it is usually best to let the EntityManager or Entity constructor establish the appropriate identifiers, such as a `UUID`. For this reason Doctrine will generate entities by default with the identifier as a private property with no setter method.

Comment: Which is The differenze with ::merge()?

Comment: `Merge` attaches the Entity to the Entity Manager as `Managed`. The reason it was needed in OP's case is that the entity was not managed `(detached)`. This occurred because it was `instantiated` and was never persisted/retrieved because it had already existed (according to the OP). Thus requiring an update rather than persistence. So in the OP the Entity Manager attempted to persist the new object, was unable too since it was already there, and since the new object wasn't `managed`, an update didn't occur either.

Answer (score 13):

Or just get the managed entity rather than an empty one.

```
$data = $entityManager->getRepository('ATest')->findOne(1); // ATest is my entitity class
$data->name = "ORM Tested"; // just change the name

$entityManager->persist($data);
$entityManager->flush();
```

If the entity is already managed, persist() will update it rather than insert a new one.

Comment: If an entity is managed, calling persist is not required, persist simply tells doctrine to start managing an entity. In this case flush is enough.

Comment: Actually, whether persist is needed depends on configuration

Comment: Isn't this a double query to database just for update?

Comment: @Sejanus yes it is. I use it all the time and would love to know a more efficient way.

Comment: @Oshanz See [Tracking Policies](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html)