# How to do edit function in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have written a function for edit in symfony2, my problem is i can fetch the previous values from the database but after submitting the form the values were notr created instead a new form is creating

Here is the controller

```
      public function editAction($id){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $profile= $em->getRepository('TcprofileBundle:TcProfiles')
    ->find($id);

        $profile_form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile);
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array('content' => $this->renderView('TcprofileBundle:Default:create.html.twig',array('form' => $profile_form->createView()))));
        return $response;

}
```

Html.twig file

```
 <div class="edit01"><a href="#!{{ path('tcprofile_edit',{ 'id': profile.getId}) }}"> Edit Profile </a></div>
```

I'm fetching the old values, so i put if loop for condition check like this

controller

```
 public function editAction($id){

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $profile= $em->getRepository('TcprofileBundle:TcProfiles')
    ->find($id);
    if(!$id){
    $profile_form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile);
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('content' => $this->renderView('TcprofileBundle:Default:create.html.twig',array('form' => $profile_form->createView()))));
    return $response;
    }else{
        $profile->upload();
        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();


    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('content' => $this->renderView('TcprofileBundle:Default:create.html.twig',array('form' => $profile_form->createView()))));
    return $response;
 }
}
```

Its not getting output Pls help me if i gone wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$em->merge($profile)` instead of `$em->persist($profile)` when updating an entity. Please [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646026/doctrine-2-update-from-entity) post

Comment: if i use merge, i'm getting exception as The class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Tc\PlayerBundle\Entity, Tc\profileBundle\Entity, Tc\StatusBundle\Entity, Tc\PhotoBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity, Tc\UserBundle\Entity

Comment: simply remove the persist() or merge() and try once again it will work.