# Doctrine Merge is not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting the following json data from the client. JSON contains the parent and child details as below -

```
{
  id : 1,
  name : "Parent"
  children : [
      { id : 1, name : "A" },
      { id : 2, name : "B" }
   ]
}
```

I am mapping these json data to Parent and Child Object.

#### Parent

```
class Parent{


    /** @Id @Column(type="integer",name="order_no") @GeneratedValue * */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Child",cascade={"merge"}, mappedBy="parent" )
     */
    protected $children;

}
```

#### Child

```
class SalesOrderDetail extends BaseEntity {

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue * */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="parent")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
     */
    protected $salesOrder;

}
```

So far so good.

Now the issue is when I am trying to merge the parent

```
$em->merge($parent)
```

I am getting the following error. Note : The entire object parent and children are unmanaged object so I am trying to merge. If I just merge parent it works find but getting error if I am trying to save entire content of parent and its children.

> Type: Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException Message: Multiple
>   non-persisted new entities were found through the given association
>   graph: * A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\Parent#itemSet' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Ziletech\Database\Entity\Child@0000000052218380000000007058b4a6. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\Child#__toString()' to get a clue. * A new
>   entity was found through the relationship
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\Parent#itemSet' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Ziletech\Database\Entity\Child@0000000052218071000000007058b4a6. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'Ziletech\Database\Entity\Child#__toString()' to get a clue.

Comment: DId you actually do what the error suggests? Either `$em->persist()` or add `@ManyToOne(targetEntity="parent",cascade={"persist"})` ?

Comment: `persist` will not help since I want to update the data, not to save new one.

Comment: More answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646026/doctrine-2-update-from-entity)

Comment: I have seen that already. I am also doing the persist. Its working for one level but not with the children that is the main issue.

Comment: How did you craete your object?

Comment: I created the object and assigned those value manually. So basically it is the undamaged object.